# React to Windows shutdown within .Net managed service before other services have been shut down

Tags: c#, windows-services, shutdown

### Context

I have created a .Net 'managed' Windows service in C#. While starting, my service creates some processes that are relied on by other applications (and, potentially in future, other services), and these processes must be available for the entire lifetime of those applications (and services). While stopping, my service will kill these processes, and my service also relies on a third party service for some of its actions. When Windows is shutting down my service needs to prepare some aspects of the system for shutdown, however these preparations must not occur when the service is simply being stopped.

So far, I have not succeeded in fulfilling all of these requirements at the same time. This may imply that a redesign is in order - perhaps the shutdown-only actions should be performed by a completely different service, or perhaps by a UI application could perform the shutdown-only actions while using `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` and its friends. Alternatively, it may be possible and sensible to achieve what I want through a single service, I just haven't worked out how to do it yet.

### My question

Can I achieve all that I want through a single service, and if so how can this be achieved in a safe a well-behaved manner? Is this a good idea? If not, what is a suitable alternative?

### My investigation and experimentation so far

- Idea 1: Keep my services's `CanStop` property as `true` and override the `OnStop` method provided by `ServiceBase`:

  - Result: `OnStop` is never called during a Windows shutdown, even if `CanShutdown` is set to `false`.
- Idea 2: Set my service's `CanShutdown` property to `true` and override the `OnShutdown` method provided by `ServiceBase`.

  - Result: There is no guarantee that my service's `OnShutdown` will be called before the third party service has been stopped / shutdown, and also, because the `On...` methods are called in their own threads within a managed service, it is extremely likely that the third party service will be trying to respond to shutdown at the same time as my service.
- Idea 3: Configure my service to accept the 'preshutdown' command as a custom command using reflection and the [SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996(v=vs.85).aspx) value. Override the `OnCustomCommand` method and react to [SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx) 'custom' command. [An example](https://web.archive.org/web/20170107010457/www.sivachandran.in/2012_03_01_archive.html).

  - Result: My service can now react during the preshutdown state of Windows, however once the service is marked as accepting preshutdown commands it will never receive a shutdown command, even if `CanShutdown` is set to `true`.

Idea 3 is close to what I want, but I do not like it for two main reasons:

- My service must shut itself down from within its preshutdown implementation, which means that both the shutdown-only steps and the stopping steps must be completed within the 'preshutdown' period. In other words I cannot perform the shutdown-only actions during preshutdown, and then separately at actual shutdown perform the stopping actions. If any service or application that relies on the processes created by my service tries to shutdown after my service has responded to a 'preshutdown' request they will no longer have the ability to interact with those processes during their own shutdown. This can be mitigated against if...

  - ...I can set the preshutdown order for services then I can ensure that services are safe. This [seems to involve](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2008/02/04/ws2008-service-shutdown-and-crash-handling/) the `PreShutDownOrder` key within `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`.
  - ...it can be guaranteed that all applications are stopped before any services are sent the 'preshutdown' command then applications will be safe. I do not know where I can find this guarantee in the documentation, assuming it exists.
- By using the custom command setup we may be circumventing aspects of the 'managed' service system (e.g. putting the service into the appropriate PENDING state followed by the appropriate STOPPED state), which may have unintended consequences - e.g. if in future I did want to delay a little would I be able to call `RequestAdditionalTime` from within my `OnPreshutdown` method, or would I need to use lower-level functions for this, or would this not be possible at all? More importantly, how will this affect using the `PreShutDownOrder` registry key - does adding the preshutdown command to the list of `acceptedCommands` qualify the service for pershutdown ordering?

As you can see there is further investigation that I can perform, however I have reached the point where I feel that it might be time to get some external expertise to nudge me in the right direction. Which is why I have posted this question. Thanks for reading to the end!

Comment: My first question whenever someone says something along the lines of "When Windows is shutting down my service needs to prepare some aspects of the system for shutdown" - what happens if you experience a sudden power failure? How do you recover when power is restored? If the answer is "we can't", you've probably got a problem. If the answer is "we can recover just fine doing X, Y and Z" then *why is that not an adequate solution all of the time*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Excellent point. I am in the process of re-assessing the situation to determine how much of what I am trying to achieve is actually a necessity, and how much is a holdover from the legacy system I am trying to improve (i.e. the legacy system needed some work done on shutdown, but just accepted that some shutdown routes weren't covered and did what it could to ensure that people wouldn't use those routes). I am still curious about preshutdown order of managed services and similar, but will perhaps create new questions for those once my re-assessment is complete.

Comment: FWIW - When I tried playing with this, I couldn't find any reasonable way to make the default ServiceBase class do Preshutdown so I just ended up rewriting it... But then I decided for my scenario it was probably good enough to use OnStop and have a Group Policy Shutdown script to tell my service to stop early during shutdowns. There are some drawbacks to this approach too...